# How to get the ID of a dynamically generated button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help.  I have a page where I display database records as a bootstrap button pill in a display div.  I also have an Ajax Submit input that saves new records to the database and dynamically creates a button pill for the new record using the db record id for the button id.  The jQuery below allows me to click on the new dynamically created button but it always displays ID = 1 and not the ID shown in view source.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Code of Button Pills created from PHP:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 mx-auto mb-3">
        <div class="decision-box">
            <div class="decision-icon bg-orange-grad"><img src="../assets/img/logos/Sparck-Logo-Icon-Lg-White.png" alt="Sparck-Logo-Icon-Lg" width="40" height="40" /></div>
            <div class="decision-text">
                <form id="accolorform">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="colorsave">
                    <input type="hidden" name="interesttype" value="Favorite Color">
                    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>">
                    Favorite Color:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="text" class="form-control-inline col-auto no-border no-shadow" id="ac_color" name="interest" placeholder="Type something" autocomplete="off" style="min-width: 200px;">
                    <span class="float-right" style="margin-right: 15px;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" id="colorbtn">Add</button>
                    </span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="color_pills">
        <?php if(!empty($resultlist) && isset($resultlist)){
            foreach($resultlist as $r){ 
                if($r['interesttype'] = "Favorite Color"){ ?>
                <button id="btn<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="btnpill" title="Are you sure you want to delete <?php echo $r['interest']; ?>?"><?php echo $r['interest']; ?> <i id="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="fal fa-minus-circle delete"></i></button>
                <?php }
            }
        }?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code of jQuery aJax that creates dynamic button

```
$("#accolorform").validate({
    rules: {
        ac_color: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        ac_color: {
            required: 'Please select a Color'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function(id){
                //alert("Color Added");
                var name = $("#ac_color").val();
                var newpill = '<button id="btn'+id+'" class="btnpill" title="Are you sure you want to delete '+name+'?">'+name+' <i id="'+id+'" class="fal fa-minus-circle delete"></i></button>';
                $("#color_pills").append(newpill);
                $("#accolorform")[0].reset();
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Code of Ajax Delete where I am trying to grab dynamic button id:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){                  
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var title = $('#btn'+id).attr('title');
    var string = 'source=interests&id='+ id ;

    if (confirm(title)) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxdelete.php",
            data: string,
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
                $('#btn'+id).remove();
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

The above code looks like it should work and view source shows a button tag that is formatted like the ones created by PHP that work perfectly.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you add a live version of your site/code.

Comment: If you `console.log(id)` _immediately after your `var id = ....;` - is it correct?

Comment: Also, please read the [help] on how to ask, particularly including an [mcve]

Comment: Hey Guys - thanks.  I can't add a live version of this particular site but let me see if I can provide a fiddle version that shows the issue.

Comment: Cale_b I will try the console comment and see what I get.  Thanks.

Comment: Caleb_b when I send the id out to the console the button with the id that was just added through Ajax displays as ID 1 but when Ilook at the ID of the button through view source it is ID 14 so something clearly isn't capturing properly.

Comment: Well the fiddle I created worked perfectly (https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/279877/) so not sure where I am going wrong in my code but I will start pulling it apart to see what is happening.